# What happened to DISM checkHealth, scanHealth and restoreHealth?

Tags: windows-10

I'm trying to repair a windows 10 system.

So far I've managed to create a bootable windows 10 repair disk (writable CD) and have managed to boot to a command prompt. Following various threads I've used `sfc /SCANNOW` to confirm that my protected windows files are all ok.

I then used `chkdsk /r /f /x`  to tell me that I have half a dozen disk errors (which chkdsk repeatedly fails to fix)

I then moved on to DISM (ver 10.0.18362.900). All the threads I followed mentioned using checkHealth, scanHealth and restoreHealth.

Non of these options seem to be available with my version of DISM, I think I have the latest version (windows last updated itself a few days ago) what are the current equivalents of checkHealth, scanHealth and restoreHealth ?

Update - Ramhound is correct. After failing to get my command to run I typed

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>DISM.exe /?
```

To see what options were available and I got this listing.

```
Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.19041.572


DISM.exe [dism_options] {Imaging_command} [<Imaging_arguments>]
DISM.exe {/Image:<path_to_offline_image> | /Online} [dism_options]
         {servicing_command} [<servicing_arguments>]

DESCRIPTION:

  DISM enumerates, installs, uninstalls, configures, and updates features
  and packages in Windows images. The commands that are available depend
  on the image being serviced and whether the image is offline or running.


GENERIC IMAGING COMMANDS:

  /Split-Image            - Splits an existing .wim file into multiple
                            read-only split WIM (SWM) files.
  /Apply-Image            - Applies an image.
  /Get-MountedImageInfo   - Displays information about mounted WIM and VHD
                            images.
  /Get-ImageInfo          - Displays information about images in a WIM, a VHD
                            or a FFU file.
  /Commit-Image           - Saves changes to a mounted WIM or VHD image.
  /Unmount-Image          - Unmounts a mounted WIM or VHD image.
  /Mount-Image            - Mounts an image from a WIM or VHD file.
  /Remount-Image          - Recovers an orphaned image mount directory.
  /Cleanup-Mountpoints    - Deletes resources associated with corrupted
                            mounted images.

WIM COMMANDS:

  /Apply-CustomDataImage  - Dehydrates files contained in the custom data image.
  /Capture-CustomImage    - Captures customizations into a delta WIM file on a
                            WIMBoot system. Captured directories include all
                            subfolders and data.
  /Get-WIMBootEntry       - Displays WIMBoot configuration entries for the
                            specified disk volume.
  /Update-WIMBootEntry    - Updates WIMBoot configuration entry for the
                            specified disk volume.
  /List-Image             - Displays a list of the files and folders in a
                            specified image.
  /Delete-Image           - Deletes the specified volume image from a WIM file
                            that has multiple volume images.
  /Export-Image           - Exports a copy of the specified image to another
                            file.
  /Append-Image           - Adds another image to a WIM file.
  /Capture-Image          - Captures an image of a drive into a new WIM file.
                            Captured directories include all subfolders and
                            data.
  /Get-MountedWimInfo     - Displays information about mounted WIM images.
  /Get-WimInfo            - Displays information about images in a WIM file.
  /Commit-Wim             - Saves changes to a mounted WIM image.
  /Unmount-Wim            - Unmounts a mounted WIM image.
  /Mount-Wim              - Mounts an image from a WIM file.
  /Remount-Wim            - Recovers an orphaned WIM mount directory.
  /Cleanup-Wim            - Deletes resources associated with mounted WIM
                            images that are corrupted.

FFU COMMANDS:

  /Capture-Ffu            - Captures a physical disk image into a new FFU file.
  /Apply-Ffu              - Applies an .ffu image.
  /Split-Ffu              - Splits an existing .ffu file into multiple read-only
                            split FFU files.
  /Optimize-Ffu           - Optimizes a FFU file so that it can be applied to storage
                            of a different size.

IMAGE SPECIFICATIONS:

  /Online                 - Targets the running operating system.
  /Image                  - Specifies the path to the root directory of an
                            offline Windows image.

DISM OPTIONS:

  /English                - Displays command line output in English.
  /Format                 - Specifies the report output format.
  /WinDir                 - Specifies the path to the Windows directory.
  /SysDriveDir            - Specifies the path to the system-loader file named
                            BootMgr.
  /LogPath                - Specifies the logfile path.
  /LogLevel               - Specifies the output level shown in the log (1-4).
  /NoRestart              - Suppresses automatic reboots and reboot prompts.
  /Quiet                  - Suppresses all output except for error messages.
  /ScratchDir             - Specifies the path to a scratch directory.

For more information about these DISM options and their arguments, specify an
option immediately before /?.

  Examples:
    DISM.exe /Mount-Wim /?
    DISM.exe /ScratchDir /?
    DISM.exe /Image:C:\test\offline /?
    DISM.exe /Online /?
```

Which mentions none of the options I was looking for!
checkHealth, scanHealth or restoreHealth

Comment: Can you provide us the exact commands you are running and the error you received?  **The commands still exist.**  I suspect your major problem is the fact, your disk has bad sectors, there is no easy fix for that problem outside of hardware replacement and restoring from a backup.  I suspect you are using `/Online` which wouldn't be invalid within WinRE

Comment: Thanks Ramhound - see my update for what I did wrong! BTW I have fully accepted that I need hardware replacement and a restore, I'm just trying to understand more about what's wrong and why.

Comment: `dism /online /?` (more specifically `dism /online /Cleanup-Image /?` displays the output you are expecting. However, you cannot use `/online`, if you booted to a Windows Recovery Environment (WinRE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After failing to get my command to run I typed `DISM.exe /?`

You are running the incorrect command.  The full output of the correct command is the following:

[image]

> None of these options seem to be available with my version of DISM, I think I have the latest version (windows last updated itself a few days ago) what are the current equivalents of checkHealth, scanHealth and restoreHealth?

The options do indeed exist.  The correct options would be `/CheckHealth`, `/ScanHealth`, and `/RestoreHealth`

> So far I've managed to create a bootable windows 10 repair disk (writable CD) and have managed to boot to a command prompt. Following various threads, I've used sfc /SCANNOW to confirm that my protected windows files are all ok.

You won't be able to use /Online within WinRE.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're typing commands incorrectly
Run your Command Prompt as administrator option then type the following command

`DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth`
`DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth`
`DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`

Type the following command to repair the Windows 10 image and press Enter:

`DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:F:\Sources\install.wim`

I also want you know that an active internet connection is required while running this command